# Use strstr() in every line

Tags: php, strstr

I want to use strstr(), to delete everything before a word.
I already have this here:

```
$file = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$deleted = strstr($file, 'word');
echo $deleted;
```

But this, is only for one line! I need, to delete everything before a word on every single line in my txt file.

I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Her I just get all lines into a array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). Then I go through each element with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and remove everything before "word" with [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php))

```
$file = file('text.txt');
$deleted = array_map(function($line){
    return strstr($line, "word");
}, $file);

echo implode("<br />", $deleted);
```

Example file:

```
test word test2
test word test
```

Output:

```
word test2 
word test
```

Comment: Actually I think in this case array_walk would be a better choice. It won't create a new array with the file contents, so array_map is less memory efficient in this case.
array_walk($file,function(&$line){
    $line = strstr($line, "word");
});

Comment: @amrhady It's also a way :D You can choose what you want (With array_map you just can keep the original file in the array)